# Printing a node from BST

Tags: java

I have a code similar to this one:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-closest-element-binary-search-tree/

For this algorithm, it will print out 17. However, I want to print it out as 
`17 is the node closest to 18`

How is that possible? Do I need to create a toString method? If so, how can it be written?

Answer (score 1):

simply replace this:

```
System.out.println( maxDiff(root, k));
```

with this:

```
System.out.println( maxDiff(root, k) + " is the node closest to " + k);
```